# RecyclerView with dynamic sections

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have to list consumed data from an API in the `RecyclerView` divided by sections, and the name of that section I get by the API, however the app closes when it arrives in the `onBindViewHolder` with the exception

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: [package], PID: 25882 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 2 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)

at NewPatrimonio.Adapter.PatrimonioReferenciaAdapter.onBindViewHolder(PatrimonioReferenciaAdapter.java:32)
```

[**Like this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B15k6.png)

**MyJson:**

```
[
    {
        "familia": "ATENDIMENTO",
        "patrimonios": [
            {
                "descricao": "PORTEIRO",
                "controle": "68D60C5DFFF27C6D7B6E6D2BF7C9E8B0",
                "quantidade": 0
            },
            {
                "descricao": "RECEPCIONISTA",
                "controle": "CBC9D1C219BAF179310A2C9A5AE94921",
                "quantidade": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "familia": "COLABORADORES",
        "patrimonios": [
            {
                "descricao": "EQUIPE DE ADMINISTRAÇÃO",
                "controle": "ADAD1F3A829F53387354E97FE3DD9026",
                "quantidade": 1
            },
            {
                "descricao": "EQUIPE DE ATENDIMENTO",
                "controle": "959BCCAEE13EB0E9A62AB7231077B0F2",
                "quantidade": 0
            },
            {
                "descricao": "EQUIPE DE JARDINAGEM",
                "controle": "798ABCFCA7ECFD727B751CC42C1E3E77",
                "quantidade": 0
            },
            {
                "descricao": "EQUIPE DE LIMPEZA",
                "controle": "3E2F32AB45C9EC327DD4A105BB838FC9",
                "quantidade": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "familia": "GERAL",
        "patrimonios": [
            {
                "descricao": "AJUDANTE",
                "controle": "11F08FC1F04E361F661DC76820AAABB7",
                "quantidade": 1
            },
            {
                "descricao": "FISCAL",
                "controle": "EEFC72871E5201D5752F12BF97B8368B",
                "quantidade": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "familia": "LIMPEZA",
        "patrimonios": [
            {
                "descricao": "FAXINEIRO",
                "controle": "A84EB5A2B0B25FCA905DC6DDC07B9598",
                "quantidade": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**MyModel:**

```
public class ModelNovoReferencia {

    @SerializedName("familia")
    @Expose
    private String familia;
    @SerializedName("patrimonios")
    @Expose
    private List<Patrimonio> patrimonios = null;

    public String getFamilia() {
        return familia;
    }

    public void setFamilia(String familia) {
        this.familia = familia;
    }

    public List<Patrimonio> getPatrimonios() {
        return patrimonios;
    }

    public void setPatrimonios(List<Patrimonio> patrimonios) {
        this.patrimonios = patrimonios;
    }

    public class Patrimonio {

        @SerializedName("descricao")
        @Expose
        private String descricao;
        @SerializedName("controle")
        @Expose
        private String controle;
        @SerializedName("quantidade")
        @Expose
        private Integer quantidade;

        public String getDescricao() {
            return descricao;
        }

        public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
            this.descricao = descricao;
        }

        public String getControle() {
            return controle;
        }

        public void setControle(String controle) {
            this.controle = controle;
        }

        public Integer getQuantidade() {
            return quantidade;
        }

        public void setQuantidade(Integer quantidade) {
            this.quantidade = quantidade;
        }
    }
}
```

**MyAdapter:**

```
public class PatrimonioReferenciaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PatrimonioReferenciaAdapter.ReferenciaVH> {
    List<ModelNovoReferencia> mListaReferencia;
    ModelNovoReferencia.Patrimonio patrimonio;

    public PatrimonioReferenciaAdapter(List<ModelNovoReferencia> mDadosReferencia) {
        this.mListaReferencia = mDadosReferencia;
    }

    @Override
    public ReferenciaVH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemListaRelacao = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_novo_referencia, parent, false);
        return new ReferenciaVH(itemListaRelacao);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ReferenciaVH holder, int position) {
        holder.txtFamilia.setText(mListaReferencia.get(position).getFamilia());
        holder.txtDescricao.setText(mListaReferencia.get(position).getPatrimonios().get(position).getDescricao());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mListaReferencia.size();
    }

    public class ReferenciaVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtFamilia, txtDescricao, txtQuantidade;

        public ReferenciaVH(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtFamilia = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtFamilia);
            txtDescricao = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescricaoRef);
            txtQuantidade = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtQtdRef);
        }
    }
}
```

**MyRow:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFamilia"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Sem família"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtFamilia">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDescricaoRef"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtQtdRef"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Quantidade já cadastrados"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtDescricaoRef" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong or what is the correct implementation to do?

Comment: I think the error is cause by `.getPatrimonios().get(position)` I need more information to help.

Comment: the issue is most likely here, getPatrimonios().get(position).getDescricao()), how do you know that the list is the same as adapter size? Use a log to get the child size or use the first position

Comment: I edited my question and added the Json return I got from the API. I also believe that the error is in this line where you said, but how do I get the position of the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

> ```
> holder.txtDescricao.setText(mListaReferencia.get(position).getPatrimonios().get(position).getDescricao());
> ```

Specifically, the problem is in the double `get()` call:

> ```
> mListaReferencia.get(position).getPatrimonios().get(position)
> ```

The `position` argument for `onBindViewHolder()` can only be used to index into `mListaReferencia`, and can't be used to index into the `patrimonios` sub-list. How you solve this will depend on exactly what you want the final behavior to be.

It seems likely that what you really want is actually quite complicated (a `RecyclerView` that uses two different view types, one to display `ModelNovoReferencia.familia` and one to display `Patrimonio` information). I'm not going to give a full tutorial on how to do that here; just search around for "RecyclerView multiple view types".

For now, you can fix the problem by changing your `onBindViewHolder()` to something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ReferenciaVH holder, int position) {
    holder.txtFamilia.setText(mListaReferencia.get(position).getFamilia());
    holder.txtDescricao.setText("" + mListaReferencia.get(position).getPatrimonios().size());
}
```

Comment: I made the change but it gave me another error. But it helped me a lot with the research suggestion, I was not aware of it. Thank you!

Comment: @MRah `FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: PID: 29962 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2 at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:338)`

Comment: That's from not being able to get the resource that you are trying to get text from, update the complete error log

Comment: @JonasVieira make sure you include the empty string in the `setText()` call I posted (e.g. it should be `setText("" + ...)`). If you don't android will think you're referencing a string resource instead of just trying to display text that happens to be a number.